Generates some space between the chart and the bottom of the outer container in Apex Chart
Using the Donut Apex Chart with legend position as bottom and I want the height of the chart to be 260px like the outer div of height:260px but it generates the height of the chart container as 227.7px. So it generates some space between the chart and the bottom of the outer container.
donutOption =
{
"series": [10800,0,16800,4800],
"labels": ["Legent (1)","Legent (2)","Legent (3)","Legent (4)"],
"chart": {
"type": "donut",
"width": "100%",
"height": "260",
},
"legend": {
"position": "bottom",
},
}

enter image description here
